# In iOS 9 splash screen shows black and multi colours?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, splash-screen

while open the old version project in to ios 9 the splash screen was shows in black screen and it displays the images in multi colors,please anyone help me for find the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a change in Xcode7 iOS 9 onwards. They have modified Launchscreen(Black screen we will get).If you change deployment target means you can see the previous launch screen.
Only empty view controller is present so we have make changes on it.

Comment: Ok I will check that, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help...@Uma

Comment: it's ok.. @Saravanakumar

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

I am using Xcode 7 and my iPhone 6 is upgraded to IOS9. I was using Launchscreen.storyboard and was getting Black LaunchScreen.

I solved it by following steps:

```
1. I removed Launch screen interface file base name from info.plist
2. Under General Tab,in Launch ScreenImage use assets Catalogs, I set
images for iOS 8,iOS 7 and iOS 6 iPhone portrait.
```

My app is now running successfully with LaunchScreen.

Comment: Hi , I am having the same problem, I am using xcode 9.0.1 any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the black launch screen issue with the new iOS 9 project I built using Unity (5.2). To fix that I added the image that I want to show as the launch image to the LaunchScreen-iPad.xib file's Image view.